# Installing Colemak on Fedora

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am struggling with installing colemak on my Fedora 36 instance.
I am using the following procedure:

```
wget https://colemak.com/pub/unix/colemak-1.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf colemak-1.0.tar.gz
cd colemak-1.0
setxkbmap us; xmodmap xmodmap/xmodmap.colemak && xset r 66
```

Yet it does not seem to change anything.
I've also tried:

```
setxkbmap us -variant colemak
```

With everything no error messages. Yet no change either.

Optimally I would love to add the layout to the gnome settings.
I am using Wayland as a Display server.

Thanks in advance

Greetings

Ceus

Comment: Have you tried logging in using Xorg?  None of the X commands you’ve included in the question are going to work in Wayland.

Comment: No I have not tried this. I honestly struggled a lot getting my nvidia drivers in Wayland. There has to be a command for Wayland :)

Answer (score 0):

Fedora has Colemak available by default, iirc (at least there is an option to set it when doing a fresh install). Therefore, it should be possible to enable it in the OS without having to install third party software.

I'm on my mobile right now, so I can't do this myself, but try this:

To list available layouts

```
localectl list-keymaps | grep colemak
```

To set your layout

```
localectl set-keymap YOURLAYOUT
```

---

**EDIT:** If you are using GNOME, you can go do the following:

1. Open 'Settings'.
2. Go to 'Keyboard'.
3. Under 'Input Sources' there is a '+' sign - press that.
4. In the pop-up window, press '⋮' and write "colemak".
5. Navigate to the preferred language and click it.
6. There are the options for the keyboard layout - select the one you want.

As a little side note: in the navbar, on the desktop, the input source selector will be in the upper-right hand corner. You might have to manually select the preferred input.

Comment: Hey I've tried this approach. No errors and the output of localectl status is: ```  System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us-colemak
      X11 Layout: us
``` Yet no change when I type. I could not find what VC Keymap means and the X11 Keymap stays at US. But I wonder why even X11... shouldnt I change it for wayland ?

Comment: That's odd... Did you run the commands as `root`? You could try to set colemak for X11, too, by using `localectl set-x11-keymap YOURLAYOUT` and then reboot your system. I've used colemak with Fedora, so I know it works. However, I set it during installation.

Comment: I've tried this. I get FAILED TO SET Keymap: specified keymap could not be compiled, refusing as invalid. Yet with us it works. US-colemak on the other hand does not work. Even though it gets listed as present with list-keymaps. And I've tried running as root. No change. Thanks for your help btw <3

Comment: And colemak by itself does also not work :sweat_smile:

Comment: The output of list-x11-keymap-variants lists multiple colemak options, none of wich work...

Comment: I'll be back home in a couple of hours and test on my PC and let you know :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot about this. Please see my updated answer.